# Creating a list out of input fields in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a form for creating a task, and when creating it, user is asked to select which employees will be assigned to it. There may be just one employee or even up to 10. I allow user to dynamically create those input fields on the go, but the array that i get after the form submition looks like this:

```
array(
    'Event' => array(
        'project_id' => '62',
        'user_id' => '23',
        'user_id2' => '24',
        'user_id4' => '28',
        'user_id8' => '30',
        'hours' => '6',
        'minutes' => '0',
        'assignment' => '',
        'material' => 'safsaf',
        'date' => '2013-10-12',
    )
)
```

The problem is I do not know how to iterate over the user_ids. 
Is it possible to save the IDs as a list? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: What does your form look like, especially the inputs that define the employees? And have you set up a proper [HABTM relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) between events and employees?

Comment: You need to use HABTM

Comment: Well, not really, that is the only situation where I need to use it. I create new input fields by jQuery if users clicks on "add more".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CakePHP's [find('list')](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) to retrieve the $users in an `key=>value` array, then set the `multiple` attribute of the input to true:

```
echo $this->Form->select('Model.field', $users, array('multiple' => true));
```

> $attributes['multiple'] If ‘multiple’ has been set to true for an
>   input that outputs a select, the select will allow multiple
>   selections:

Comment: Worked a charm. It is just that I do not really like how the list looks in the final output. Users needs to know that CTRL buttons needs to be pressed which may not be obvious in some cases.

Comment: Change to `'multiple'=>'checkbox'` instead of `'multiple'=>true`  (this is all in the CakePHP Book online.